# Euler Lagrange Equation for a Particular Functional

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

How can I show (using the Euler Lagrange Equations) that : for constants (mass and time) $m,h>0$

\begin{align} h\inf \bigg\{ &\int_0^h m\left\|  \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\xi (t)   \right\|^2 : \xi \in C^1([0,h];\mathbb{R}^d), \\
&(\xi,m\dot{\xi})(0)=(q,p), \ (\xi,m\dot{\xi})(h)=(q',p') \bigg\} \\
=&\|p'-p \|^2 + 12\left\| \frac{m}{h}(q'-q)-\frac{p'-p}{2} \right\|^2. 
\end{align}

Im confused how to apply these equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Euler Lagrange equation, you can show that the infinimum is indeed reached for a function $\varphi \in C^1([0,h],\mathbb{R}^d)$ that verifies :

$$ \frac{d^4 \varphi}{dt^4}(t)=0, \quad \forall t \in [0,h]\\
 \varphi(0)=q\\
\varphi'(0)=\frac{p}{m}\\
 \varphi(h)=q'\\
\varphi'(h)=\frac{p'}{m}
$$

The first equation gives you that there exists constants $(c_3,c_2,c_1,c_0)\in (\mathbb{R}^d)^4$  such as :
$$\varphi(t)=c_3t^3 +c_2 t^2 + c_1t+ c_0$$
and you find the four constants using the 4 boundary conditions.

After that all you need to compute is :

$$h m \int_0^h ||\underbrace{6 c_3 t+2 c_2}_{\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\varphi(t)}||^2  \ \mathrm{d}t$$
which should give you the good formula.

Comment: Where does the fact that $\varphi\in C^1 $ come into things? And maybe a bad question but are cubics the only functions that have third derivative equal zero, maybe there is some strange non-polynomial function.

Comment: The fact that $\varphi \in C^1$ is just a condition that needs to be verify for the minimum. It is indeed the case for this polynomial function.

Comment: By integration, you can show it is only possible for $\varphi$ to be a polynomial function, of max degree inferior to $3$.